# how to pass arguments from an plack app to an mojolicious app enabled in builder?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, plack

given the example plack app using lots of middleware components and an mojolicious app
enabled in builder (see below), how can i pass parameters from the app.psgi to Mojolicious
without using the ugly %ENV hack shown? of cause passing an config is just an example, this could be any scalar/object.

app.psgi

```
use Plack::Builder;

$ENV{CONFIG} = {...};

builder {
    ...
    Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('MyApp');
};
```

MyApp.pm

```
package MyApp;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {

    my $self = shift;
    my $r = $self->routes;

    $self->config( $ENV{CONFIG} );

    $r->route('/')->to('home#');        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question and is most easily tackled by looking at the source. In your example you rightly use

```
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('MyApp');
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Commands.pm#L106) shows that `start_app` is a rather simple wrapper:

```
sub start_app {
  my $self = shift;
  return Mojo::Server->new->build_app(shift)->start(@_);
}
```

It turns out that `build_app` is [as well](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojo/Server.pm#L18):

```
sub build_app {
  my ($self, $app) = @_;
  local $ENV{MOJO_EXE};
  return $app->new unless my $e = Mojo::Loader->new->load($app);
  die ref $e ? $e : qq{Couldn't find application class "$app".\n};
}
```

returning a new instance of your app's class. The Mojolicious class's `new` function is [more involved](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L61), but in the end, [it just calls the familiar `startup` method and returns the instance](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L93).

This means that you cannot easily pass arguments to the `startup` method from your middleware wrapper, used in the standard way. I can think of two mechanisms to accomplish what you want to do: 1) write your own `build_app` function to replace the server's method but which passes arguments to `$app->new` (which would get passed to `startup` in turn) or 2) write your own `start_app` function which could call another `startup`-like function.

```
# in MyApp.pm

sub startup {
  ... # as before
}

sub after_startup {
  ... # your new code here,
      # or even most of what was in `startup` before
}
```

and

```
# app.psgi

builder {
  ...
  my $app = Mojo::Server->new->build_app(shift);
  $app->after_startup(@your_args_here);
  $app->start(@_);
}
```

Comment: i also asked the source but at some point gave up. i thought there has to be an easy way to pass parameters. but as you are one of the core developers... maybe something like `Mojolicious::Commands->enable_app('MyApp', @my_params)` should be added to Mojolicious ;-) ?

Comment: you are welcome to hop on the [IRC channel](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Contributing#Feature_requests): #mojo on irc.perl.org