# Passing an argument to a mojolicious app

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to give an argument when calling an mojolicious app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594352/how-to-pass-arguments-from-an-plack-app-to-an-mojolicious-app-enabled-in-builder) indicates that it's not easily done, at least not five years ago. By looking at the [documentation](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Commands#start_app), it looks like there is an option for it (or I'm I reading this wrong?).

```
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('MyApp');
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app(MyApp => @ARGV);
```

If it's indeed possible, how do I access it from the startup function? I've tried some of the most obvious one, like...

```
sub startup {
    my ($self, $arg) = @_;
    ....
```

This didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the source. When you do `start_app`, it eventually runs [`$app->start`](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.70/lib/Mojolicious.pm#L196), which passes `@ARGV` to `$self->commands->run`. That's another instance of [Mojolicious::Commands](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Commands), which parses the args and figures out what to do with them.

My best guess is you need to implement a [Mojolicious::Command](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Command), and then you can pass along your args. That could be as simple as setting properties in the app object (which might exist already, not sure).